# Ошибка типа type mismatch - функциq возвращает дефолтный тип Unit

Tags: функции, рекурсия, scala, функциональное-программирование

Мне нужно написать функцию, которая принимает два списка строк и возвращает один, соединяя элементы на одинаковых позициях в один. Я смог сделать с обычной рекурсией, но с хвостовой возникли проблемы.

Вот код:

```
// Simple recursion
def merge1(listA: List[String], listB: List[String]): List[String] = (listA, listB) match {
  case (Nil, Nil) => Nil
  case (head1 :: tail1, Nil) => head1 :: merge1(tail1, Nil)
  case (Nil, head2 :: tail2) => head2 :: merge1(Nil, tail2)
  case (head1 :: tail1, head2 :: tail2) => head1 + head2 :: merge1(tail1, tail2)
}

merge1 (List("a", "b", "c", "d"), List("e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"));

// Tail recursion
def merge2 (listA: List[String], listB: List[String]): List[String] = {
  def merge2Helper (listA: List[String], listB: List[String], listACC: List[String]): List[String] =
(listA, listB) match {
      case (Nil, Nil) => Nil
      case (head1 :: tail1, Nil) => merge2Helper(tail1, listB, listACC ::: List(head1))
      case (Nil, head2 :: tail2) => merge2Helper(tail2, listB, listACC ::: List(head2))
      case (head1 :: tail1, head2 :: tail2) => merge2Helper(tail1, tail2, listACC ::: List(head1 + head2))
}
}

merge2 (List("a", "b", "c", "d"), List("e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"));
```

> Ошибка типа type mismatch, результат функции merge2Helper ожидается List[String], но возвращается дефолтный тип Unit

Answer (score 2):

Проблема у Вас в том, что в функции `merge2` происходит лишь декларация функции `merge2Helper` и больше ничего.
Вы нигде не вызываете эту функцию. Давайте вызовем ее в последней строчке в теле функции `merge2`. Инициируем аккумулятор пустым списком:

```
merge2Helper(listA, listB, List.empty[String])
```

Но теперь Ваша функция все равно не работает, так как допущены логические ошибки:

1. Последний шаг рекурсии приведет сюда:

   > case (Nil, Nil) => Nil

   Результатом выполнения функции `merge2Helper` ВСЕГДА пустой список. Надо бы возвращать аккумулятор `listACC`. Вам понятно почему в `merge1` надо возвращать `Nil`, а в `merge2` аккумулятор?
2. > case (Nil, head2 :: tail2) => merge2Helper(tail2, listB, listACC ::: List(head2))

   Вот тут Вы меняете местами `listA` и `listB` ставя на место `listA` хвост от `listB`. А на место хвоста от `listB` Вы ставите `listB` целиком. На каждом шаге рекурсии входные аргументы одинаковые и Ваша функция бесконечно зацикливается.

Итого:

```
def merge2 (listA: List[String], listB: List[String]): List[String] = {
    def merge2Helper (listA: List[String], listB: List[String], listACC: List[String]): List[String] =
      (listA, listB) match {
        case (Nil, Nil) => listACC
        case (head1 :: tail1, Nil) => merge2Helper(tail1, listB, listACC ::: List(head1))
        case (Nil, head2 :: tail2) => merge2Helper(listA, tail2, listACC ::: List(head2))
        case (head1 :: tail1, head2 :: tail2) => merge2Helper(tail1, tail2, listACC ::: List(head1 + head2))
      }

    merge2Helper(listA, listB, Nil)
  }
```

---

**P.S. А можно проще?**

Для компоновки двух листов в `scala` используется метод `zip`, который попарно объединяет элементы первого и второго листа в список пар:

```
List("a","b").zip(List("c","d")) // List(("a","c"),("b","d"))
```

Однако `zip` работает только для листов одинаковой длины, попросту отбрасывая "лишние" элементы.
Выручит `zipAll`, который умеет принимать значение по-умолчанию для первого или второго листа, на случай, если в каком то из них "закончатся" элементы:

```
List("a","b").zipAll(List("c","d","e"), "", "") // List(("a","c"),("b","d"),("","e"))
```

Ну а дальше дело за малым. Просто сложим пары строк в строки:

```
List(("a","c"),("b","d"),("","e")).map{case (a,b) => a + b} // List("ac","bd","e")
```

Итого:

```
val l1 = List("a", "b", "c", "d")
val l2 = List("e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")
val t = l1.zipAll(l2,"","").map{case (a,b) => a+b}
```